# Ajax Form With Google Invisible Recaptcha

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

My code:

```js
function onSubmit(token) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit").click(function() {
      var name = $("#name").val();
      var email = $("#email").val();
      var password = $("#password").val();
      var contact = $("#contact").val();

      // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
      var dataString = 'name1=' + name + '&email1=' + email + '&password1=' + password + '&contact1=' + contact;

      //AJAX code to submit form.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
          alert(result);
        }
      });

      return false;
    });
  });

  $("#i-recaptcha").submit();

};
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

<form id='i-recaptcha'>

  <input type="text" id="name" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="email" /><br/>
  <input type="password" id="password" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="contact" /><br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lcjvi4UAAAAAIR7_ckItF2HfMEFHx427WUDdGDk" data-callback="onSubmit" />

</form>
```

**Problem:**

When the user clicks on `submit` button for the first time, the captcha box appears, as expected.

But after completing the captcha verification, the box closes, and the form do not get submitted.

The user needs to click on the `submit` button again, in order to submit the form.

**Expected result:**

Click on submit button > Recaptcha box Appear > Verified > Automatically submit the form

**Original Result**

Click on submit button > Recaptcha box Appear > Verified > Click on submit button again > submit the form

I thought this line will submit the form after completing captcha

`$( "#i-recaptcha" ).submit();`

Comment: Do you need to place $(document).ready inside the function. Can you not place it outside the function onSubmit.

Comment: I Tried, same result @Amit

Comment: i-recaptcha is the name of the form. the form does not have method and action specified in its tag like form method="post" action="page_url". Where will line $( "#i-recaptcha" ).submit(); actually submit the form? When you are calling $.ajax, you are specifying type and page_url for the ajax call scope. That does not get appended to form attributes.

Comment: You may need to add method and action to form in javascript, something like $( "#i-recaptcha" ).attr("method", "post");$( "#i-recaptcha" ).attr('action', "url";);

Comment: WHere to place it @Amit ?

Comment: before $( "#i-recaptcha" ).submit();

Comment: No, now the form do not even get submitted @Amit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("#submit").click(function() {`

This function gets executed, when `#submit` button is clicked. Change it to `submit()`, function.

Here is the full code:

```js
function onSubmit(token) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#i-recaptcha").submit(function() {
      var name = $("#name").val();
      var email = $("#email").val();
      var password = $("#password").val();
      var contact = $("#contact").val();

      // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
      var dataString = 'name1=' + name + '&email1=' + email + '&password1=' + password + '&contact1=' + contact;

      //AJAX code to submit form.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
          alert(result);
        }
      });

      return false;
    });
     $("#i-recaptcha").submit();
  });

 

};
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

<form id='i-recaptcha'>

  <input type="text" id="name" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="email" /><br/>
  <input type="password" id="password" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="contact" /><br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lcjvi4UAAAAAIR7_ckItF2HfMEFHx427WUDdGDk" data-callback="onSubmit" />

</form>
```