# How to use Google Recaptcha before doing an AJAX Post

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, recaptcha

I have a form which submits data to a Kulahub API, using AJAX, but I need to verify first that the user filling in the form is genuine, then upon getting the OK from Google, do the AJAX post, however, I can't find a simple solution.

The Post works fine, and submits the data to the API.

Its the recaptcha, i have tried the following threads solutions; [Invisible ReCaptcha with jQuery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837623/invisible-recaptcha-with-jquery-ajax)
[Invisible reCaptcha AJAX Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158855/invisible-recaptcha-ajax-call)
[Google Invisible Recaptcha Using Jquery Ajax and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48411167/google-invisible-recaptcha-using-jquery-ajax-and-php)
[Ajax Form With Google Invisible Recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974166/ajax-form-with-google-invisible-recaptcha)

I am building the site in Umbraco, now i was under the impression i can verify the google recaptcha result, using ajax or javascript?

Here is the post which works;

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://www.kulahub.net/Api/FormAdd",
            data: $('#kulaHubForm').serialize(),
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success Posted");
                localStorage.setItem("isSubbed", "1");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                console.log("bad");
            }
        });
```

And here is the form

```
<form id="kulaHubForm" data-toggle="validator" novalidate="true"  class="newsletter-signup">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Subscribe to our Newsletter »</legend>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="">
            <div class="form-group" style="position: static;">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="">
            <div class="form-group" style="position: static;">
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="">
            <div class="form-group" style="position: static;">
                <label for="eadd">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" id="eadd" class="form-control" value="@email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="">  
            <div class="form-group" style="position: static;">
                <label for="cname">Company Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="cname" class="form-control" name="custom_company" placeholder="Company Name" >
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @*Honeypot*@
            <input type="checkbox" id="conCheckBox" name="conCheckBox" value="value1" style="display:none !important" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" name="flowers" id="flowers" style="" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off"/>
            <input type="text" name="daisys" id="daisys" value="Subscription Form SAN" style="display:none !important;color:black !important;" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off"> 
        @*End Honey, Pot?*@

        <div class="col-md-4" style="">  
            <div class="form-group" style="position: static;">
                <label for="jtitle">Job Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="jtitle" class="form-control" name="custom_position" placeholder="Job Title" >
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="">  
            <div class="form-group" style="position: static;">
                <label for="telno">Telephone Number</label>
                <input type="text" id="telno" class="form-control" name="custom_telno" placeholder="Telephone Number" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="hidden" name="ClientId" value="XXX">
            <input type="hidden" name="FormTypeId" value="XXXX">
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="">
            <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my site key" data-callback='onSubmit'>Submit</button>

        </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the full call here

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script>
    function onSubmit(token) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://www.kulahub.net/Api/FormAdd",
            data: $('#kulaHubForm').serialize(),
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success Posted");
                localStorage.setItem("isSubbed", "1");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                console.log("bad");
            }
        });
        grecaptcha.reset();// to reset their widget for any other tries
    }
    </script>
```

But I just can't deduce what Google actually wants you to do, I think their documentation is lacking, especially for beginners.

I don't really care which version of Recaptcha I use, I wanted to use the newest but ultimately that looked even less documented than 2 online, so I went with 2 invisible here, but am open to whatever will work.

Is this possible? Thank you

Comment: The idea is that you send the completed captcha value to your server along with the rest of your form. Then your server side code, as part of its validation routine, should forward the request to recaptcha's server for verification, and check the response. If you don't do this, there's a chance someone could either fake the response or just disable the captcha in the browser, and thereby bypass the validation it provides

Comment: This might help you (for V2) https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: Ah, I may have been misunderstanding it then, do you *have* to have some underlying server code, be it .net or php etc? Thanks for your response

Comment: Well if you want to ensure that no one is faking the code or removing the captcha protection entirely, then yes. And the whole enterprise would be pretty useless if you didn't ensure that. You can make it part of your API's validation layer

Comment: If you're not in control of the API, and it isn't expected to receive and process a captcha, then you would indeed need some server side code of your own - you'd submit the whole form to your server, including the captcha data. At your server you'd verify the captcha, and then if it's ok your server would make a new Http request to the API to forward on the form data. It would then collect the response from the API and provide it back to the client

Comment: If you're using Umbraco already to host the site, then you've got a framework in place for doing that

Comment: This may help from the JS side. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612879/google-recaptcha-how-to-make-required/29613089#29613089